# TFS - Cannot configure reporting services: "The server that you specified was not found or cannot be reached"

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to configure Reporting Services for TFS2010. Upon clicking on edit in "Reporting", in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console, I'm able to configure everything without error.

**Warehouse:**

*Server:* INDEPENDIENTE01

*Database:* Tfs_Warehouse

*(Clicking test connection shows up a green mark)*

**Analysis Services**

*Server:* INDEPENDIENTE01

*Database:* Tfs_Analysis

*(Clicking test connection shows up a green mark)*

**Reports**

*Server:* INDEPENDIENTE01

*(Clicking Populate URLs shows up the correct urls)*

*Default Path:* /TfsReports

But when I click ok, I get this message:

`The server that you specified was not found or cannot be reached. Specify another server`

I have two servers, one with **TFS** and **WSS** and the other one with **SQL Server 2008**.
I already changed Report Server Database configuration to Native mode.
Tried using Network Service account and a different Account aswell.
I can access both urls (**INDEPENDIENTE01/Reports** and **INDEPENDIENTE01/ReportServer**)
And apparently I have all needed ports opened too (Otherwise I think it wouldn't even populate the urls)

My problem is similar to this one:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsreporting/thread/cfcb3031-c19a-474d-aab4-3b88ecd248e1

Except it didn't solve my problem.

(I hate those unspecific error messages, what's wrong with microsoft...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with ports, oh well.

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: Which port exactly? How does this "answer" even got upvotes, as it is more of a comment as of help? Report Server uses port 80, which will be already open in most scenarios.